# Day 2 of Primary Fermentation of beer

Tags: beer, yeast, fermentation, primary, foam

Is this what my primary fermentation should look like after a day??? 
It looks like my yeast has been sitting on top of foam..

[image: http://yfrog.com/kgfzqgkj]

Comment: Next time, you'll want to rehydrate your dry yeast, rather than sprinkling it on top of the wort.  I'm sure this brew will turn out fine, however.  As another poster said, RDWHAHB.

Comment: +1 for pic! :) much easier for others to pick up any advice that way,

Answer (score 5):

That looks like yeast that is sitting on top of a foam (krausen) that was produced by more yeast.  I assume you poured dry yeast directly into the fermenter?  All it means is that some of it clumped up top instead of sinking down.  The rest took over quickly and have been happily munching away.  A worst case scenario is the yeast was old and some of it had died.  This would have a greater potential to produce off flavors.  If you didn't have foam, you would probably want to re-pitch.  As it is, relax, don't worry, have a homebrew.

If you want to avoid this from happening in the future, make a starter the day or two before and double check the date on the yeast package.

Comment: So does this look normal?? Is everything looking fine?

Comment: Yes!  Close the damn lid and stop worrying!