# Yeast on primary fermenting foam

Tags: beer, yeast, fermentation, primary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Day 2 of Primary Fermentation of beer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/day-2-of-primary-fermentation-of-beer)

Is this what it should look like day 2? I sprinkled the yeast on top yesterday, and today it looks like it foamed a bit and looks like the yeast is sitting on top..

[image: yeast in action]

Answer (score 2):

Looks great! Get the top back on before you let something nasty in there! Try really hard to ignore it for about 2 weeks and then check on it again.  Good beer takes time, RDWHAHB.

Answer (score 1):

Looks perfect  What you see sitting on top is trub and it's fine.

Comment: yesterday the trub was getting bigger and bigger, and this morning it has gone down.. is it supposed to do this?

Comment: Yep! It will start to fall near the end of fermentation (still check with a hydrometer though). Sounds like it's going fine.

Comment: I call the stuff on top "dirty head".  Am I wrong?

Comment: Actually, what I'm used to hearing is "krausen" is the foam, and "trub" is all the sediment on the bottom. But really, as long as whoever you're talking to knows what you mean...